# Java Generics - subclass of T in; same subclass of T out

Tags: java, generics

This is officially doing my head in!

What I want to do is pass a type into a method, and get the same type back. Exactly this:

```
public <T> T get(T in) {
    return in;
}
```

Only I want T to be a subclass of an abstract base class, not just any old class. Kind of something like this:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> T get(<T extends BaseClass> in) {
    return in;
}
```

But as we all know; it doesn't quite work that way does it.

Comment: Why doesn't it work that way?

Comment: @TimBender why don't you try it first?

Comment: I did. Aside from over thinking it, it does work. I was sort of pointing at the phrasing of the question.

Comment: @TimBender; actually I did try it. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: And the compiler tells you about incorrect tokens and points to the use of `<` as the first character in the parameter portion of the get method. The reason for the error is that the compiler expects a type declaration or no parameters. You've already told the compiler what `T` is once, you don't have to do it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tried it but doesn't this work?

```
public <T extends BaseClass> T get(T in) {
    return in;
}
```

Comment: I've copied the syntax above and it really is that simple! Thanks @armandino, I was 2 hours into it with no exit plan! You know how it is some days.